# set value on textfield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application I want set value to textfield. I want to do same like here

```
<input type="text" value ="something">
```

My question how could i do the same on rails view.

```
   <h1>New location</h1>

<% form_for(@location) do |f| %>
  <%=  f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :address %><br />
    <%=  f.text_field :address %>

  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :latitude %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :latitude %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :longitude %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :longitude %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', locations_path %>
```

Answer (score 5):

By passing the `value` argument

```
<%= f.text_field :latitude, :value => 17 %>
```